# Given x coordinate difference find the angular difference

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

A point on a circle moved horizontally by $x$. How to find $\alpha$ in the picture below, knowing $x$, circle radius and center?

[image: problem visualisation]

I'm pretty sure this is doable but I just can't reach the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, since the curvature of a circle is constant, the problem is stable by rotation and translation. If you move both points the same way across the circle, $\Delta x$ won't be changed. Therefore, let us rotate the circle so that one of the two red points is vertically aligned with the center of the circle. We get the following figure:

[image]

In the bottom right angled triangle, let us consider the angle $\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha$. It is the angle that completes the right angle at the center of the circle. One has:

$$ \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\right) = \sin \alpha = \frac{\Delta x}{r},$$

hence

$$ \boxed{\alpha = \arcsin \frac{\Delta x}{r} + 2k\pi}. $$

In other words, we just basically shrank the circle to the unit circle (divided every distance by factor $r$ and placed it at the origin) and interpreted the distance $\frac{\Delta x}{r}$ as its definition in this circle, which is precisely being the quantity $\sin \alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some trigonometry.

Let $C$ be the center, with coordinates $(x_0,y_0)$. Let the two points be $P_1$ and $P_2$ with $P_1$ below and to the left of $P_2$. Let their coordinates be $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$.

The coordinates of the point $P_2$ are given by
$$x_2 = x_0 + r \cos(\theta)
$$
$$y_2 = y_0 + r \sin(\theta)
$$
where $\theta$ is the signed angle from the ray based at $C$ and extending to the right to the ray based at $C$ and extending through $P_2$. You can now solve for 
$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{r} (x_2-x_0)
$$
$$\sin(\theta) = \frac{1}{r} (y_2-y_0)
$$
Similarly, 
$$x_1 = x_0 + r \cos(\theta+\alpha) = x_0 + r (\cos(\theta)\cos(\alpha)-\sin(\theta)\sin(\alpha))
$$
$$y_1 = y_0 + r \sin(\theta+\alpha) = y_0 + r (\cos(\theta) \sin(\alpha) + \cos(\alpha) \sin(\theta))
$$
Now plug in the expressions obtained above for $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$. You'll get two equations in the unknown expressions $\cos(\alpha)$ and $\sin(\alpha)$ which you can solve. Using inverse trig functions gives you $\alpha$.